# $T:f(x)\to f(x-1)+x^3f'''(x)/3$ Find the Jordan normal form and a Jordan basis for $T$.

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Let $T\in \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{P_3}(\mathbb{C})$ be the operator 
$$T:f(x)\to f(x-1)+\frac{x^3f'''(x)}{3}$$ 
Find the Jordan normal form and a Jordan basis for $T$.

Answer (score 2):

If we take the canonical basis $1,x,x^2,x^3$, then 
$$
f(x)\longmapsto f(x-1)
$$
maps $1\longmapsto 1$, $x\longmapsto x-1$, $x^2\longmapsto x^2-2x+1$, $x^3\longmapsto x^3-3x^2+3x-1$, so it has matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &-1&1&-1\\
0 &1&-2&3\\
0 &0&1&-3\\
0 &0&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
And $f(x)\longmapsto x^3 f'''(x)/3$ maps $1$, $x$, and $x^2$ to $0$, and maps $x^3$ to $2x^3$. Thus its matrix is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&0\\ 
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&2
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then matrix for $T$ is then the sum of those two, namely
$$
T=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &-1&1&-1\\
0 &1&-2&3\\
0 &0&1&-3\\
0 &0&0&3\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Since $T$ is triangular, we see immediately that the eigenvalues are $1$ (with multiplicity 3), and $3$.

Solving the two systems $T-\lambda I$ for $\lambda$ equal to  $1$ and $3$ respectively, we find that the eigenvectors for $1$ are scalar multiples of  $$v_1=\begin {bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end {bmatrix} $$ (that is, the constant polynomials) and the eigenvectors for $3$ are scalar multiples of 
$$
v_4=\begin{bmatrix}
-11\\12\\
-6\\
4\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Since the algebraic multiplicity of $1$ is greater then the geometric one, to complete the basis we need to look at the generalized eigenvectors. That is, the kernel of $$(T-I)^2
=\begin{bmatrix}
0 &-1&1&-1\\
0 &0&-2&3\\
0 &0&0&-3\\
0 &0&0&2\\
\end{bmatrix}^2
 =\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0&2&-8\\
0 &0&0&12\\
0 &0&0&-6\\
0 &0&0&4\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and of
 $$(T-I)^3
=\begin{bmatrix}
0 &-1&1&-1\\
0 &0&-2&3\\
0 &0&0&-3\\
0 &0&0&2\\
\end{bmatrix}^3
 =\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0&0&-22\\
0 &0&0&24\\
0 &0&0&-12\\
0 &0&0&8\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The kernel of $(T-I)^2$

We need to choose $v_2,v_3$ in such a way that $Tv_2=v_1+v_2$, $Tv_3=v_2+v_3$. These turn out to be
$$
v_2=\begin{bmatrix}0\\-1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ v_3=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1/2\\1/2\\0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Thus a Jordan basis for $T$ is given by 
$$
p_1(x)=1,\ \ \ p_2(x)=-x,\ \ \ p_3(x)=\frac{x+x^2}2,\ \ \ p_4(x)=4x^3-6x^2+12x-11,
$$
and the Jordan form of $T$ is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0\\ 0&1&1&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&3\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for this generous effort. I am a self-studier, so would you please be kind enough to clarify for me when you can use the (convenient) canonical basis {$1,x,x^2, \dots$} vs. the Gram-Schmidt orthonormal version of the basis. Also, could I further impose on you; I am studying Axler, "LA Done Right," which doesn't seem to present a method of actually determining  the Jordan basis. Is there a reference you might suggest so that I can understand what you did beginning with: "We need to chose $v_2, v_3$, etc. With regards,

Comment: In general, an orthonormal basis is much better because it allows you to find the coefficients of a vector explicitly: $x=\sum_k \langle x,e_k\rangle e_k$. But in the case of polynomials, the natural way of expressing a polynomial is in the basis $\{1,x,x^2,\ldots\}$ so the coefficients are already given; so this basis would be preferred in most cases.

Comment: There was a typo after "We need", now corrected. I was looking for the vectors so that $T$ behaves like that Jordan form: in the basis where the matrix has the Jordan form as given, one needs $$Tv_1=v_1,\ \ Tv_2=v_1+v_2,\ \ Tv_3=v_2+v_3,\ \ Tv_4=3v_4.$$

Comment: Finally, regarding textbooks, I'm not the one for you. I learned linear algebra "coming down" from functional analysis, so I cannot really comment on good reads.